# How to implement average reduction in caffe using Scale

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, scale, caffe

I want to implement Average-reduction in `caffe` , not as part of the input layer. 
Also I want it to be channel-wise, of some constant values (different from each other). I have tried with `Scale` Layer and didn't find a way to subtract each channel individually.

I will glad for some help

### EDIT

I was able to figure it out using `bias` layer, which as i understand is used for implementing `Scale` layer.

#### I'm sharing my solution:

first create the prototxt:

```
layer {
    bottom: "bottom_layer"
    top: "top_layer"
    name: "mean_reduction"
    type: "Bias"
}
```

After it, injecting the data to the **layer params**, like this:

```
net.params['mean_reduction'][0].data[...] = *the desired blob*
```

Comment: you should post your solution as an "answer" not as part of the question.